# Android intent call gives error in asynctask onPostExecute() method

Tags: android, android-intent, android-asynctask

Hey my question has to do with intents and asynctask in android I have the following code where i launch the asynctask from a button

```
Button.OnClickListener buttonSignin = new Button.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) 
                    getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                if (networkInfo == null && networkInfo.isConnected() == false) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                   
                } 
                else if(editUserName.getText().length() == 0 && editPassword.getText().length() == 0){
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please fill required details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }else{
                   enteredUserName = editUserName.getText().toString();
                    password = editPassword.getText().toString();

                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", enteredUserName));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
                   atn = new AsyncTaskNetwork();
                   atn.execute("http://staff.faharitech.com/raphael/hirizi/api/public/v1/user/login",nameValuePairs);

                // new sendLoginDetails().execute("http://staff.faharitech.com/raphael/hirizi/api/public/v1/user/login");       
    }
```

the asynctask is in a different public class which is here

```
public class AsyncTaskNetwork extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, String> {
    ConnectToAPI conn;
    LoginActivity la;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String result = null;
         try {
             conn = new ConnectToAPI();
             String url = (String) params[0];
             List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs =  ( List<NameValuePair>) params[1];
             result = conn.postData(url, nameValuePairs);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        la = new LoginActivity();
        la.parseJsonData(result);
    }

}
```

finally the method being called onPostExecute is in the same class as the button which launched the asynctask

```
public void parseJsonData(String result){
    try{
        JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);          

        if(json_data != null){
        JSONObject jObj = json_data.getJSONObject("user");
        if(jObj != null){
        JSONObject jObj2 =null;
        username = jObj.getString("username");
        System.out.println(username);
        token = jObj.getString("token");
        System.out.println(token);
        fullName = jObj.getString("full name");
        System.out.println(fullName);
        profilePic = jObj.getString("profilePic");
        System.out.println(profilePic);         
        System.out.println(jObj.getString("stores"));
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(jObj.getString("stores"));


        for(int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++){
            jObj2 = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            sName = jObj2.getString("name");
            System.out.println(sName);
            sId = jObj2.getString("id");
            System.out.println(sId);
            logo = jObj2.getString("logo");
            System.out.println(logo);       
        }


        displayResults = username + " " + token;
        }
        else{
        JSONObject jObjMessage = json_data.getJSONObject("message");
        errMessage = jObjMessage.getString("message");
        displayResults = errMessage;
        }
        }
        }catch(JSONException e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());

    }

    if(username != null && token != null){
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NavigationActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);          
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),errMessage, 10000000).show();
    }
}
```

my question is the error arises on the intent call a nullpointerexception something to do with the context which context should I use there other than getApplicationContext()

update the logcat

```
    08-19 14:59:45.649: E/AndroidRuntime(6897): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-19 14:59:45.649: E/AndroidRuntime(6897): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-19 14:59:45.649: E/AndroidRuntime(6897):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:135)
08-19 14:59:45.649: E/AndroidRuntime(6897):     at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:75)
08-19 14:59:45.649: E/AndroidRuntime(6897):     at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:3491)
08-19 14:59:45.649: E/AndroidRuntime(6897):     at com.faharitech.hirizi.LoginActivity.parseJsonData(LoginActivity.java:336)
08-19 14:59:45.649: E/AndroidRuntime(6897):     at com.faharitech.hirizi.AsyncTaskNetwork.onPostExecute(AsyncTaskNetwork.java:36)
08-19 14:59:45.649: E/AndroidRuntime(6897):     at com.faharitech.hirizi.AsyncTaskNetwork.onPostExecute(AsyncTaskNetwork.java:1)
08-19 14:59:45.649: E/AndroidRuntime(6897):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
08-19 14:59:45.649: E/AndroidRuntime(6897):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
08-19 14:59:45.649: E/AndroidRuntime(6897):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
08-19 14:59:45.649: E/AndroidRuntime(6897):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-19 14:59:45.649: E/AndroidRuntime(6897):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-19 14:59:45.649: E/AndroidRuntime(6897):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-19 14:59:45.649: E/AndroidRuntime(6897):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-19 14:59:45.649: E/AndroidRuntime(6897):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-19 14:59:45.649: E/AndroidRuntime(6897):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-19 14:59:45.649: E/AndroidRuntime(6897):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-19 14:59:45.649: E/AndroidRuntime(6897):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I can't imagine this `la = new LoginActivity();` working in any Android app. Why would you do that?

Comment: please paste the logcat.

Comment: make sure getApplicationContext() is not null.

Comment: thanks @RiteshGune but how do I do that or is there an alternative i could use

Comment: you can pass the activity context and use that instead of application context. That would solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use your activity name dot this, sample:

```
YourActivity.this
```

Comment: change this:
    `@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        la = new LoginActivity();
        la.parseJsonData(result);
    }
`

to this:

    `@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        this.parseJsonData(result);
    }
`

Answer (score 0):

does toast alone work?
Try defining the asyntask inside the activity class if the other answer doesn't work.(it should)

Comment: copy the AsyncTaskNetwork class inside the class that is using it

Answer (score 0):

Make a constructor of your `AsyncTaskNetwork` and take `Context` as argument. Declare a member variable of `AsyncTaskNetwork` as `Context mContext` and initialized in constructor. i.e.

```
public class AsyncTaskNetwork extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, String> {
    ConnectToAPI conn;
    LoginActivity la;
    Context mContext;


public AsyncTaskNetwork(Context context){

    this.mContext=context;
  }
 .........
}
```

At the time to call the `Intent`, you can pass this context. i.e.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,NavigationActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks @Mukesh Kumar the problem is the intent call is being made from the same class where the asynctask was launched that is LoginActivity so mContext alone is not working do you have another solution